# How to help my 6-year-old who does a lot of self talking, becomes aggressive at school and lacks concentration in studies?

Tags: primary-schooler, school, socialization, focus, aggression

My 6-year-old son is in year 1 and he was doing really good in studies until last month. But, he is a bit lazy and does not usually take care of his belongings and is never ready to take any initiative to participate in any kind of activity. He is usually the last one to follow the command or instructions.

Consequently, children have been trying to teach him and being bossy to him with the intention to correct him. As he has been bullied by other children for his slow behaviour, he likes to be isolated and is not interested in making friends.

In fact, his frustration has turned into very aggressive behaviour and he kicks and hits most of those who used to bully him in the past without any response from them in the present, and if an adult tries to stop him, he gets aggressive with them as well. The other day, he tried to bite his teacher's hand when she was trying to save another child from being hit by my son. He does funny things in front of the whole class to seek attention and keep smiling for no reason.

We are very concerned about his socialisation and poor concentration skills. His growth is normal and appetite is good apart from when he remained sick for the last couple of months due to tonsillitis. He is good in toileting. And recently he learnt cycling in 3 weeks without training wheels.

He does a lot of self talking and usually use terms he learnt from cartoons. He has started hitting us at home too now when we stop him from watching TV or playing games on iPad.

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE! What strategies have you looked at so far for disciplining, and what is the school/teacher saying? Have you discussed these behavior concerns with a pediatrician or school counselor?

Comment: You have many details, but they will not be enough to help.  A child (or anyone, for that matter) who demonstrates such behavior should be seen by a professional for a comprehensive approach.

Comment: How much TV/iPad time do you allow him? How much sleep does he get? What country are you in? (asking that last one because available resources and support will be different)

Answer (score 1):

I would look into autism. A lot of what you have described are traits if autistic children. And all are different and it's a wide spectrum so jjust because he learns some things quickly or is good for the most part doesn't mean it's not possible.

Comment: I agree. I would push very hard for a specialist to have a look at him as soon as possible. If he is autistic he needs support, and ordinary disciplinary strategies risk really damaging his confidence.